# chef server and chef client connectivity

Tags: chef-infra

If we open firewall between chef server and client , is one way fire-wall opening is sufficient from Chef client to chef server?

Since chef server does not execute anything on the CHEF clients and client reads the chef cookbook and updates itself, is the one way communication is sufficient?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, Chef Server is just a REST API. All connections are always from the client to the server.